# Merging child array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Is it possible to merge an array of children with the same _id in MongoDB? In the example below I want to merge the parameters of attributes with _id of "5f3553c483477525987a6852".

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5f3553c483477525987a6851",
        "subject": "ENGLISH",
        "attributes": [
            {
                "_id": "5f3553c483477525987a6852",
                "attribute": {
                    "_id": "5f34efb685ede72a0c0a54d4",
                    "attribute": "SEATWORK"
                },
                "parameters": {
                    "_id": "5f3553c483477525987a6853",
                    "parameter": {
                        "_id": "5f35539e83477525987a684e",
                        "parameter": "HOMEROOM"
                    },
                    "percentage_allocation": 20
                }
            },
            {
                "_id": "5f3553c483477525987a6852",
                "attribute": {
                    "_id": "5f34efb685ede72a0c0a54d4",
                    "attribute": "SEATWORK"
                },
                "parameters": {
                    "_id": "5f35578d786afe026451470c",
                    "parameter": {
                        "_id": "5f3553a783477525987a684f",
                        "parameter": "PERFORMANCE"
                    },
                    "percentage_allocation": 20
                }
            },
            {
                "_id": "5f3553c483477525987a6856",
                "attribute": {
                    "_id": "5f35320efec3522aa0f47b02",
                    "attribute": "QUARTERLY ASSESSMENT"
                },
                "parameters": {
                    "_id": "5f3553c483477525987a6857",
                    "parameter": {
                        "_id": "5f35539e83477525987a684e",
                        "parameter": "HOMEROOM"
                    },
                    "percentage_allocation": 60
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

How to achieve this desired result, the parameters of the attributes have become an array of their respective parents with the same attributes._id. Thank you!

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5f3553c483477525987a6851",
        "subject": "subject": "ENGLISH",
        "attributes": [
            {
                "_id": "5f3553c483477525987a6852",
                "attribute": {
                    "_id": "5f34efb685ede72a0c0a54d4",
                    "attribute": "SEATWORK"
                },
                "parameters": [{
                    "_id": "5f3553c483477525987a6853",
                    "parameter": {
                        "_id": "5f35539e83477525987a684e",
                        "parameter": "HOMEROOM"
                    },
                    "percentage_allocation": 20
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5f35578d786afe026451470c",
                    "parameter": {
                        "_id": "5f3553a783477525987a684f",
                        "parameter": "PERFORMANCE"
                    },
                    "percentage_allocation": 20
                }]
            },
            {
                "_id": "5f3553c483477525987a6856",
                "attribute": {
                    "_id": "5f35320efec3522aa0f47b02",
                    "attribute": "QUARTERLY ASSESSMENT"
                },
                "parameters": [{
                    "_id": "5f3553c483477525987a6857",
                    "parameter": {
                        "_id": "5f35539e83477525987a684e",
                        "parameter": "HOMEROOM"
                    },
                    "percentage_allocation": 60
                }]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Have you tried [$mergeobjects](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/index.html#mergeobjects-aggregation)?

Comment: I tried but still cannot achieve the format I want Thanks for the information.